# Probability of randomly selecting a number in the set $2^n$ from positive even numbers?

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-writing, logarithms

Given a set of even positive integers ($2,4,6,...$), less than or equal to $m$, what is the probability that a random element is included in the set of powers of two (i.e. for all $2^n\leq m$)? I would assume it would involve a straightforward modification of
\begin{equation}
\frac{\lfloor{\log_2 m}\rfloor+1}{m}
\end{equation}
which is the equivalent question on a set of all integers ($1,2,3,...$). Also, how would the original question be proven rigorously? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "*How would it be proven rigorously?*"  Induction.  "*which is the equivalent question on a set of* **all integers**..." No such equivalent question exists, there is no uniform distribution on a countably infinite set possible.  You could talk about the *limit* of the probability as $m$ grows large, which is a distinct concept, and you will find that it approaches zero.

Comment: As for dealing with the sample space exclusively being even natural numbers rather than just natural numbers themselves... divide each element in your list by $2$ and you are back to the question where it was all naturals instead.  $2x$ from $(2,4,6,8,\dots,m)$ is a power of two iff the corresponding $x$ from $(1,2,3,4,\dots,\frac{m}{2})$ is a power of two.

Comment: @JMoravitz How would the inductive step be defined? Is this strong induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $m$ is even (if it is odd, substitute it with $(m-1) \ $).

$2^n \leq m \implies n \leq \frac{\ln m}{\ln 2}$

So, $k = max(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{\ln m}{\ln 2} \right\rfloor$

Also if the last element in the set $\{2 \ 4 \ 6 \ ...\}$ is $m$, then we have $ \displaystyle \frac{m}{2}$ elements in the set.

Then the probability of a randomly selected element to be in the set of powers of two is,

$ \displaystyle P = \frac{k}{m/2} = \frac{2k}{m}  $

Answer (score 1):

The modification derives from the fact that now you have half    the numbers you can choose from but any number which is a power of $2$ is still included (except for $1$) so the probability is

$$\frac{\lfloor{\log_2(m- m \text{ mod } 2)}\rfloor}{\frac{m-m \text{ mod } 2}{2}}$$

I included $m \text{ mod } 2$ because when $m$ is odd the last number in the set is $m-1$.